# how to get count column

Tags: android, cursor

I'd like to get the value of Count column from cursor.

```
public Cursor getRCount(String iplace) throws SQLException
{
 try {
      String strSql = "SELECT COUNT(_id) AS RCount FROM tbName WHERE place= '" + iplace + "'";            
      return db.rawQuery(strSql, null);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("Exception on query", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried to get this count column value from cursor like below

```
Cursor cR = mDbHelper.getRCount(cplace);if (cR.getCount() > 0){long lCount = cR.getLong(0);}cR.close();}
```

I got the debug error. How to get it?

PS: Could I use nested cursors?

Comment: Are you sure this is .NET? It looks like Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [DatabaseUtils.longForQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) utility method to run the query on the db and return the value in the first column of the first row.

```
int sometotal=DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,"SELECT COUNT(_id) AS RCount FROM tbName WHERE place= '" + iplace + "'",null);
```

Comment: Thanks, Pentium. I add type cast to int.
int sometotal=(int)DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,"SELECT COUNT(_id) AS RCount FROM tbName WHERE place= '" + iplace + "'",null);

Answer (score 0):

The `Cursor` is positioned before the first row when you get it back from `rawQuery()`. Call `moveToFirst()` before attempting to use the `Cursor`, and your problem should go away.

Comment: How does the moveToFirst() method help if the Cursor is already at the beginning of the records?

Comment: @AJW: A fresh `Cursor` is *not* "already at the beginning of the records". A fresh `Cursor` has its position *before* the first row, not *on* the first row.

Comment: Gotcha.  Do you know what would be better as far as efficiency for a large database, the rawQuery method with a Cursor or the DatabaseUtils.longForQuery method?

Comment: @AJW: I do not know what `longForQuery()` does. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question on that.

Comment: Will do, ty.  p.s. enjoyed reading your Busy Coder's book 2 years ago when I first started with Java and Android.  Cheers.

Comment: @AJW: Thanks for the kind words!