# SQLite Query in Android to count rows

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I'm trying to create a simple Login form, where I compare the login id and password entered at the login screen with that stored in the database.

I'm using the following query:

```
final String DATABASE_COMPARE =
"select count(*) from users where uname=" + loginname + "and pwd=" + loginpass + ");" ;
```

The issue is, I don't know, how can I execute the above query and store the count returned.

Here's how the database table looks like ( I've manged to create the database successfully using the execSQl method)

```
private static final String
DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table users (_id integer autoincrement, "
            + "name text not null, uname primary key text not null, " 
            + "pwd text not null);";//+"phoneno text not null);";
```

Can someone kindly guide me as to how I can achieve this? If possible please provide a sample snippet to do the above task.

Answer (score 124):

[DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29) (since api:11) is useful alternative that negates the need for raw SQL(yay!).

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "users",
                "uname=? AND pwd=?", new String[] {loginname,loginpass});
```

Comment: for OS < 11, it gets NoSuchMethodError error, is there any work-around to support for OS < 11?

Comment: @Khobaib Check the answer from ghchinoy

Comment: @EduardoHerzer I found a way with cursor.getCount() directly.

Comment: @Khobaib That's not a very efficient way of doing it. You should always prefer using `SELECT COUNT(*)` and `queryNumEntries()` over retrieving all the records and seeing how many there are, ie. `cursor.getCount()`

Answer (score 120):

@scottyab the parametrized [DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, table, whereparams)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) exists at API 11 +, the one [without the whereparams exists since API 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29). The answer would have to be creating a Cursor with a db.rawQuery:

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from users where uname='" + loginname + "' and pwd='" + loginpass +"'", null);
mCount.moveToFirst();
int count= mCount.getInt(0);
mCount.close();
```

I also like @Dre's answer, with the parameterized query.

Comment: For those wondering, the parameter for `mCount.getInt()` is `columnindex`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: How would you do this for `contentResolver.query` ?

Answer (score 62):

Use an [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html).

e.g.

```
 SQLiteStatement s = mDb.compileStatement( "select count(*) from users where uname='" + loginname + "' and pwd='" + loginpass + "'; " );

  long count = s.simpleQueryForLong();
```

Comment: One thing I like about this answer vs @scottyab's answer (which IS also really good) is that you can specify a LIMIT clause in this case. This is useful when you just want to know if there are ANY rows in a table (e.g., select (count(*) > 0) from TABLE LIMIT 1) vs no rows. I'm guessing that'll be faster when the table could have no rows or a ton of rows. This is the specific case I had when searching for this...

Comment: @Teknogrebo: This is a nice answer, though I would use the parameterized version. You can use `?`s in the query and then use `bindString(int, String)` and `bindLong(int, long)` to insert the values. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement).

Answer (score 23):

See [rawQuery(String, String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) and the documentation for [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)

Your DADABASE_COMPARE SQL statement is currently invalid, `loginname` and `loginpass` won't be escaped, there is no space between `loginname` and the `and`, and you end the statement with ); instead of ; -- If you were logging in as bob with the password of password, that statement would end up as

```
select count(*) from users where uname=boband pwd=password);
```

Also, you should probably use the selectionArgs feature, instead of concatenating loginname and loginpass.

To use selectionArgs you would do something like

```
final String SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname=? AND pwd=?";

private void someMethod() {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SQL_STATEMENT, new String[] { loginname, loginpass });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you already have a Database (`db`) connection established, I think the most elegant way is to stick to the `Cursor` class, and do something like:

```
String selection = "uname = ? AND pwd = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {loginname, loginpass};
String tableName = "YourTable";
Cursor c = db.query(tableName, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
int result = c.getCount();
c.close();
return result;
```

Comment: You should at least specify a column. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used. #perfmatters

Comment: In fact if the necessary info is only a count, retrieving a single column (ID for instance) would be more than enough

Answer (score 12):

[how to get count column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817417/how-to-get-count-column)

```
final String DATABASE_COMPARE = "select count(*) from users where uname="+loginname+ "and pwd="+loginpass;

int sometotal = (int) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, DATABASE_COMPARE, null);
```

This is the most concise and precise alternative. No need to handle cursors and their closing.

Comment: Amazing - been working with Android since forever and never knew about this DatabaseUtils - Google should be better at promoting there utils...

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the count of records then you have to apply the group by on some field or apply the below query.

### Like

```
db.rawQuery("select count(field) as count_record from tablename where field =" + condition, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using ContentProvider then you can use:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, new String[] {"count(*)"},
            uname=" + loginname + " and pwd=" + loginpass, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be using:

```
myCursor.getCount();
```

on a Cursor like:

```
Cursor myCursor = db.query(table_Name, new String[] { row_Username }, 
row_Username + " =? AND " + row_Password + " =?",
new String[] { entered_Password, entered_Password }, 
null, null, null);
```

If you can think of getting away from the raw query.

Answer (score 1):

```
int nombr = 0;
Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = Value", null);
nombr = cursor.getCount();
```