# android how to check Database Table Is empty or not?

Tags: android

i want code for following concept
If Data_Base_Table is empty insert the data to Data_Base_Table.Its only one time .If already data in Data_Base_Table  means do nothing.I Wrote like this
Here am checking DataBase Table data is empty or not is it correct or not
public boolean checkDataBaseTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase dataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();

```
    String s = "SELECT * FROM"+Data_Base_Table;
    Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(s, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            //int i=cursor.getColumnCount();
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return cursor!= null ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: write a query get count on tab table

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202269/sqlite-query-in-android-to-count-rows

Answer (score 4):

Try with this code.

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null,null);
if(cursor.getCount()>0)
{
     // database not empty
} else {
    // database empty
}
```

Comment: Hi Jigar Shekh,every time calling database not empty even after uninstall and install it wil call database not empty.please reply me

Comment: @Thej, your database store in sdcard?

Comment: Hi Jigar,Thanks for Reply.My Problem solved.I didn't get ur point.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(your-table-name, columns, null, null, null);
if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    //do some stuff when there is data in the table
} else {
   //do some stuff when there is no data
}
```

Comment: if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
//just in case your cursor is null.check if it is not equal to null 
}else{

}