# I want to calculate number of rows with where clause in query

Tags: android

This code returns total number of rows. Where as i want the number of rows with `username` and `password` entered by user.

```
public boolean logInUser(String un,String pass){
    int row;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USERNAME = '" + un + "' AND PASSWORD = '" + pass + "'";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    row=c.getCount();
    return row > 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question so it is readble

Comment: Check out this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381457/1384010
Hope this will help you.

Comment: i use count function still its calculating total number of rows where clause is not working.