# Java SQL get all rows from column

Tags: java, sql

I want to get the number of rows from my database 
How can I create a method that returns the number of rows as an int?
Here's what I got but it only returns number 1

```
public int getAllId() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int x=0;
    String where = null;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS, null);


     while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {



        c.moveToNext();

    }

    db.close();
    return c.getCount();
```

Comment: By executing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE` inside your method. Show some initiative, there's plenty of information available on these things.

Comment: Yes, I looked through many of the examples and questions here but I can't adapt it to my code because I'm still such a newbie to java

Comment: The question is to broad. We can't see your code nor what you have done so far. Consider update your question please.

Comment: Updated, and please comment if downvote...

Comment: `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` returns number of rows. Why not to get result in `ResultSet` and iterate `while` until `resultSet.next()` if `resultSet != null` does this make sense

Comment: I tried with resultset but did not succeed. I'll try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it thanks to

[SQLite Query in Android to count rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202269/sqlite-query-in-android-to-count-rows)

Here's the code I came up with:

```
public int getRowCount() throws Exception {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS,
    null); 

    mCount.moveToFirst();
    int rows= mCount.getInt(0);
    mCount.close();

return rows;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using simple JDBC without any libraries you should be able to get the number of rows from the ResultSet
I did this a while back using two approaches:

1.

```
    rs.last();
    rs.getRow();
```

2.

```
      int rowcount = 0;
      while (rs.next()) { 
      // more processing here 
       rowCount++;
     }
```

but as a word of caution, I have used this only on oracle and mysql dbs. Also if the connection is ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY you will not be able to go back.

you can read more about resultSets from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Hope this helps :)