# How to get the count of the records for the following database in android?

Tags: android

I created the database like this...

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(idno VARCHAR,name VARCHAR,class VARCHAR,year VARCHAR,gender VARCHAR);");
```

I am using api23. please suggest the code .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Query in Android to count rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202269/sqlite-query-in-android-to-count-rows)

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getDBcountField () {
        // select query
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
        int recordCount = db.rawQuery(sql, null).getCount();
        db.close();
        return recordCount;
}
```

It returns you to count number of total records in the table.

**EDIT**

You already use `SQLiteDatabase db;` in your code. So use these line for getting total count of records. Only use these 2 lines.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
int recordCount = db.rawQuery(sql, null).getCount();
```

Comment: its showing "cannot resolve method getWritabaleDatabase()"

Comment: okkk.. show me.. where is you use this code. If you use in any inner class then `this` will represent inner class. Better solution is put this whole method in your DatabaseHandler Class and call from your activity().

Comment: If You use this code in your activity then just replace `this.getWritableDatabase();` with `new  your_databasehelper_class.getWritableDatabase();`.

Comment: I created the database like this
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(idno VARCHAR,name VARCHAR,class VARCHAR,year VARCHAR,gender VARCHAR);"); After inserting then on click i called the the method which you have given

Comment: see my edit.  `this.getWritableDatabase();` is used for instance/object of `SQLiteDatabase` but you already use `db` as SQLiteDatabase's object. So now only write these lines it will returns total count. Remeber db should not be null;