# Code in Sqlite that you say a value and it checks how many of those are in the column_x

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Anyone knows a code in Sqlite that you say a value and it checks how many of those are in the column_x? Imagine you say value Johnny , and it checks how many Johnnys are in the column_names.

Comment: where your approach ?? Search `like` & `count` in sqlite

Comment: I don't know , im very noob on android thats why im asking

Comment: You want to do a [count](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count) operation. With a where clause. Search about aggregation functions.

Comment: @EmanuelSobreiro read https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381457/3395198

Comment: Use Query=select COUNT() from tbl_name where column_x=Johnny
get count Like this

   

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass your column value which you want to count that how many time it present...

```
public long getCount(String column_x_Value) {
            long count;
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + column_x + "='" + column_x_Value+ "'", null);
//here column_x name of column and column_x_Value which is to be counted
           count = c.getCount();
            if (c != null && !c.isClosed())
            c.close();
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: Too much code. `SELECT Count(Name) FROM Names WHERE Name =  'Johnny'` would directly return the count, without any extra cursor operation.