SQL request alway empty
I'm new to android-studio and trying to learn this + kotlin.
I tried to do a simple count(*) request but the count always return 0.
I tried everything I could. I'm not able to find what would be the mistake and I think that there's something I shall add that I don't know.

My db is placed on Main/assets
My log shows : successfully opened database lvl_database
My database contains two filled rows and everything is well named as in the code (Table + columns)



    class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteAssetHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
   companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "lvl_database"
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    }
}

class SubLevel : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var dbHelper: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sublevel)

        dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)
        val db: SQLiteDatabase = dbHelper.writableDatabase

        // Utilisation de try-catch pour gérer les éventuelles exceptions
        try {
            val cursor: Cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Levels", null)
            val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.Sublevel_title)

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val count = cursor.getInt(0)
                textView.text = "Nombre total de lignes dans la table Levels : $count"
                Log.d("DatabaseDebug", "Count from Levels: $count")
            } else {
                textView.text = "Aucune donnée dans la table Levels"
                Log.d("DatabaseDebug", "Cursor is empty or failed to move to first.")
            }
            cursor.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DatabaseError", "Error accessing database: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        } finally {
            db.close()
        }
    }
}


How does your query perform via a DB browser like https://sqlitebrowser.org/ ?

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202269/sqlite-query-in-android-to-count-rows/8911919

Bart, I don't really see how this question is similar.
In my case I just do the most simple request (a count on my table). In DBbrowser it returns 4, in my app it returns 0.
Btw, I tried another method mentionned in this thread (SqliteStatement), it returns 0 too

No error is occurring. Usually when this happens to me, I am not looking at the same database as the code. Could another [Levels] table exist in another database file?

Unfortunately no.
It's a new project  with only 1 local database in the folder

There is nothing wrong with the functionality of your code.

Copying the code asis (most of it).
Adding the TextView to the layout as per

:-
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Sublevel_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />


Creating an SQlite database externally (with 3 rows in the Table levels) and copying it into the assets/databases folder with the file name lvl_database as per

:-



and then running the App results in:-



and the Log including:-
2024-05-07 14:11:27.489 I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database lvl_database
2024-05-07 14:11:27.491 D/DatabaseDebug: Count from Levels: 3

As such your issue is very likely with the file that has been copied into the assets/databases folder. You should probably redo the copy of the file into the assets folder ensuring that you have saved it and that it has had rows inserted into the levels table.

One thing to check is that there are no files that are the same name as the source database file but suffixed with either or both -wal and -shm as if these additional files exist, it probably means that the database has not been closed properly and if the -wal file is not empty, that there is uncommitted data.

As an example, the  above demo was done using Navicat for SQLite, this requires that Navicat itself is closed to commit the WAL data to the actual database file.



